# Returning variable from function is undefined once returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Is there any reason that this:

```
function find_parent_p(x){
    daddy = jQuery(x).parent();


    if(daddy.attr("tagName").toLowerCase() == 'p'){
        console.log(daddy,"result");
        return (daddy);
    } else {
        find_parent_p(daddy);

    }

}
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        $('img').each(function(){

            next = find_parent_p($(this));

        })


});
```

would return a jQuery object in the console (expected behaviour), where as the following returns `Undefined` All I am doing is moving the call to `console.log` outside the function, and after the call to it:

```
function find_parent_p(x){
    daddy = jQuery(x).parent();


    if(daddy.attr("tagName").toLowerCase() == 'p'){

        return (daddy);
    } else {
        find_parent_p(daddy);

    }

}
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        $('img').each(function(){

            next = find_parent_p($(this));
                    console.log(next,"result");

        })


});
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Just find the parent that has an attribute called tagName with a value of p?

Comment: Whats the purpose of find_parent_p, when you can use parent(),parents(), or closest()?

Comment: Why are you mixing $ and jQuery? Pick one!

Comment: @epascarello You may notice that I pass the & into the .ready. as the function is outside of this, it still requires me to use jQuery. It is to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing the `return` statement in your `else` condition. If your function recurses, then the top level call won't return anything, and you'll end up with `undefined`.

```
else {
    return find_parent_p(daddy);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is causing the problem, but the function only works if it finds the element immediately.

- Make `daddy` a local variable (to prevent possible conflicts with global variables)
- Return the result from the recursive call

:

```
function find_parent_p(x) {
  var daddy = jQuery(x).parent();
  if(daddy.attr("tagName").toLowerCase() == 'p') {
    return daddy;
  } else {
    return find_parent_p(daddy);
  }
}
```

Note: You can do the same using just jQuery:

```
var next = $(this).closest('p');
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out closest. I would give you the tick, but it's not strictly the best answer to the actual question, so you'll have to make do with a +1

Answer (score 0):

If you aim to get the img's parent which is p, you can use.

```
$('img').each(function(){
   next = $(this).closest('p');
   console.log(next,"result");
})
```